# Proper use of Scala traits and case objects

Tags: scala

Trying to get the hang of Scala classes and traits, here's a simple example. I want to define a class which specifies a variety of operations, that could be implemented in lots of ways. I might start with,

```
sealed trait Operations{
  def add
  def multiply
}
```

So for example, I might instantiate this class with an object does that `add` and `multiply` very sensibly,

```
case object CorrectOperations extends Operations{
    def add(a:Double,b:Double)= a+b
    def multiply(a:Double,b:Double)= a*b
}
```

And also, there could be other ways of defining those operations, such as this obviously wrong way,

```
case object SillyOperations extends Operations{
    def add(a:Double,b:Double)= a + b - 10
    def multiply(a:Double,b:Double)= a/b
}
```

I would like to pass such an instance into a function that will execute the operations in a particular way.

```
 def doOperations(a:Double,b:Double, op:operations) = {
   op.multiply(a,b) - op.add(a,b)
 }
```

I would like `doOperations` to take any object of type `operations` so that I can make use of the `add` and `multiply`, whatever they may be.

What do I need to change about `doOperations`, and what am I misunderstanding here? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't ran your code, but I suppose you got a compilation error.

If you don't define the signature of the methods in the `Operations` trait, then by default it will be interpreted as `() => Unit`.

This means that the methods in the inheriting objects are not really *overriding* the methods in the trait, but define *overloads* instead. See more about that [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164353/whats-the-difference-between-overloading-a-method-and-overriding-it-in-java). You can verify this by writing `override` in front of the method definitions in the object methods. That will force the compiler to explicitly warn you that the methods are not overriding anything from the ancestor trait, and works as a "safety net" against similar mistakes.

To fix the bug, spell out the signature of the trait like the following:

```
sealed trait Operations{
  def add(a:Double,b:Double):Double
  def multiply(a:Double,b:Double):Double
}
```

In fact, the output parameter types are not even necessary in the  methods of the inheriting objects (but note the added `override` attributes):

```
case object CorrectOperations extends Operations{
    override def add(a:Double,b:Double) = a+b
    override def multiply(a:Double,b:Double) = a*b
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So your second code block there isn't working for me, `override def add = a+b`, it appears I still need the signatures...

Comment: @keegan sorry, indeed you are right, it needs the input parameters... but not the output. See edited version.