# scala value is not a member of type parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm trying to get the hang of Scala traits and case classes. Below is a followup to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905257/proper-use-of-scala-traits-and-case-objects/29905522).

Suppose I have a simple class and an object that extends it.

```
sealed trait Operations{
    def add(a:Double,b:Double):Double
    def multiply(a:Double,b:Double):Double
}

case object CorrectOperations extends Operations{
    def add(a:Double,b:Double):Double = a+b
    def multiply(a:Double,b:Double):Double= a*b
}
```

Now I have some function that will make use of any object of type `Operations`, such as,

```
def doOperations(a:Double,b:Double, op:Operations)={ op.multiply(a,b) - op.add(a,b)}.
```

This works well, but my question is how to generalize the types of trait `Operations`, so we're not just talking about `Doubles`. So i'd like to have generic types for trait `Operations` and then type specification for each object.

Using type generics, I tried

```
sealed trait Operations[T]{
  def add(a:T,b:T):T
  def multiply(a:T,b:T):T
}

case object CorrectOperations extends Operations[Double]{
    def add(a:Double,b:Double):Double = a+b
    def multiply(a:Double,b:Double):Double= a*b
}

def doOperations[T](a:T,b:T, op:Operations[T])={ op.multiply(a,b) - op.add(a,b) },
```

with a compile error at `doOperations` - "value - is not a member of type parameter T".

So we know that `op.multiply(a,b)` will return type `T`, and the error would indicate that type `T` has no `.-` method.

How should I be thinking about achieving this generalization of trait `Operations` ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your problem, you should introduce a `subtract` method into your `Operations` trait, so that you can provide evidence that `T` has such a method (well it doesn't, but a method that does a subtraction from to `T` from another).

```
sealed trait Operations[T] {
    def add(a: T, b: T): T
    def multiply(a: T, b: T): T
    def subtract(a: T, b: T): T
}

case object CorrectOperations extends Operations[Double]{
    def add(a: Double, b: Double): Double = a + b
    def multiply(a: Double, b: Double): Double = a * b
    def subtract(a: Double, b: Double): Double = a - b
}

def doOperations[T](a: T, b: T, op: Operations[T]) =
    op.subtract(op.multiply(a,b), op.add(a,b))
```

This is basically what the [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) trait does.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Numeric. Also, look at how Numeric adds the Ops class to let you use `-` instead of `subtract`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that there is no `-` (minus) operation in your type class to subtracting your `multiply` result from your `add` result fruitlessly looks for that operator on type `T`.

Try adding `minus` to your type class:

```
sealed trait Operations[T]{
  def add(a:T,b:T):T
  def multiply(a:T,b:T):T
  def minus(a:T,b:T):T
}

def doOperations[T](a:T,b:T, op:Operations[T])=
  op.minus(op.multiply(a,b) - op.add(a,b))
```